# Intuition behind the rearrangement of terms in series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, real-numbers

Is there any intuitive reasoning as to why the rearrangement of terms in conditionally convergent series can result in nonsense but in absolutely convergent series it's perfectly fine? I've gone through the proofs but I would like the results to make intuitive sense as well.

In addition to that, are there any circumstances under which the rearrangement of an infinite amount of terms in a conditionally convergent series does not change the value the series tends towards?

Comment: As to rearranging an infinite amount of terms, simply switch each odd term with the next even term, and the limit of the partial sums will not change.

Comment: I would say that conditionally convergent series are highly non-intuitive.

Comment: Perhaps it's wise to occasionally abandon the search for an intuitive understanding of something when infinity is involved. It's a bummer though.